# Some RPC not shown in polkadot explorer

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I was checking the rpc methods in polkadot explorer and I see a lot of rpc shown as output when queried rpc-> methods.
But I don't see some of them inside the rpc field. for example rpc methods returned `chain_getRuntimeVersion`
but when I checked through field `chain` it shows only `chain_getBlock`, `chain_getFinalizedHead`etc but no `chain_getRuntimeVersion`.

Is there any particular reason behind this?

Comment: By default there are some RPC methods that are manually enforced to be included there: https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/blob/17425040ddda47d539556eeaf62b88c4240d1d42/src/json_rpc/methods.rs#L338-L462

Comment: I see. But this is actually incase of smoldot right, I'm talking more in terms of polakdot/api because when I queried api.rpc.chain.getRuntimeVersion() it failed. But api.rpc.chain.getBlock() is working so a bit confused on that

Comment: yes, because from chain the only methods that are available to execute as api.rpc.chain are chain_getBlock, chain_getBlockHash,  chain_getFinalisedHead and chain_getHeader

Comment: Sorry for the link above, the code for substrate is defined here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/rpc-api/ and your specific pallet: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/rpc-api/src/chain/mod.rs

Comment: yeh makes sense, so if I want to query chain_getRuntimeVersion, through polkadot-js or chain what do I need to enable that? Or is that not at all possible, I see that chain_getRuntimeVersion is a runtime api.